# Explode an array in Python with {} and I delimiter

Tags: python, arrays, pipe, explode

Hi I am new and trying to learn Python and Pandas. I have come across solutions online to explode DF without '{' and '|' separators. But I have not been able to find a solution specific to mine and was hoping for some help.

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Name gender message_type        code 
1      M         orange         103 
2      F                        {102|777}
3      M         {red|blue}     983
```

I want to explode the table so that each element of the array becomes its separate row

Like this

```
 Name gender message_type       code 
    1      M         orange     103 
    2      F                    102
    2      F                    777
    3      M         red        983
    3      M         blue       983
```

So far I have tried writing something like this to test on one column, but to no avail

```
df_exploded = df1['code'].apply(lambda x:[v.split('|') for v in x]).apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thank you